# Detecting "content" or "no" in a NLP/Chatbot setting

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, dialog, chatbot

I'm a researcher trying to create a chatbot which collects data from a user. In the conversation, we reach a point where the chatbot communicates "is there anything else you like about X?". From this point, we wish to either detect if the user says "no" or they give an answer with content we wish to record.

Is there any known classifiers or techniques for doing this? I would hope to use a rule-based classifier before going to something requiring training. Furthermore, if possible, I wish to detect it purely based on text and not buttons.

Thank you.

Comment: To my knowledge the answer is no... and this answer can be expressed with in a surprising number of ways: not at all, not really, I don't think so, nothing important comes to mind, I want to talk about something else [than X], I'm bored with X, no way, I'd rather talk about Y, ... I think that training a classifier is unavoidable for obtaining a reliable decision based on text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Erwan thank you for the reply. I think I will be forced to use a classifier which is trained specifically for the task at hand.